# JavaScript: $(document).ready(function () { doesn't activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

My JavaScript knowledge is limited to say the least, but I'm charged with the task of fixing a script. I've googled a bit, and only saw things about not importing jquery and calling the function before jquery as possible problems.

I don't think I made those errors.
This is the general setup of the first bit of my code. It's important that a certain python script will be executed as soon as the page is done. But whatever I want him to do, it just won't initiate.
Am I missing something obvious? Making a noob mistake?

I'm also having problems with getting the divs right, but that's for another time. Been spending nearly a week trying to get this tool to work, to no avail.....
Hopefully I made this post correctly.

EDIT:
Here's the full script:
http://pastebin.com/NMG8RMjA

It's long, and I think pretty much a mess too. Along the way I'm trying to clean things up.

Comment: If using chrome, what does it say in the console/debug?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, but I'm not sure if that's you trying to break down the problem or they're actually there in your code. Can you post the actual code you have? If functions are irrelevant, leave them out entirely, but post all the relevant parts as they are in your actual page.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Where are the `path` and `pythonscript` variables being set?

Comment: Taken from jQuery doc RE getJSON (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) "Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/."

Comment: Test if a `alert('hello');` works inside the document ready function.

Comment: Chrome console doesn´t say anything when I load the page. Only when I click on a button(that is linked to a function, thats links to a div I'm having problems with) this shows up: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined".
I'm preparing the actual code at the moment, as I cannot show all of it yet :(.
And "alert('hello');" doesn't do anything, tried that.

Comment: I have updated the main post and added a pastebin link to the full code.

Answer (score 1):

`Function() {}` will throw `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` and cause the script to abort before reaching `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Don't touch the `Function` constructor, use the `function` keyword.

(Since those functions don't do anything at all, just remove them)